# What is the best approach to Access Neo4j Data from External Application?

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I want to use `Neo4j` Graph Database for my `Android Social Media Application`, which is the best Approach to access Data from the Database.

1. `Drivers`
2. `HTTP API`

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is the HTTP API.

However, you may want to take a look at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FdlBvw_s2P8), which purports to show how to use the Java driver with Android. I have not tried that approach myself.

Comment: I saw the video, he exposes username and password, I think the best approach is creating a REST API and expose it. @cybersam